# rake pipeline sourceMap filter

Tags: rake, ember.js

I am playing around with rake pipeline to understand building emberjs apps.

Getting it to work is fairly straight forward and an example is here: https://github.com/emberjs/todos

but I am struggling to find resources on how to get the sourceMap working as a part of the pipeline so that I can view my js files separately in web inspector. [Reference](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

Has anyone been able to get this going?

Comment: There are definitely people using rake-pipeline. Adam Hawkins is also really pushing it with iridium (https://github.com/radiumsoftware/iridium/). However, I'm not sure if there's any SourceMaps integration yet. You should definitely contact him and see if you can work on getting something integrated. I for one would love to make use of it, but I have almost no knowledge of Source Maps at the moment.

Comment: @PeterWagenet Without any CLEAR sourcemaps integration/example, I dont see a way to easily use rake-pipeline for dev purposes. The JS landing on the page is combined of all files. Hence, its really hard to map errors to original files. I will try and check with Adam Hawkins.

Comment: If you use `string` mode for minispade then it evals each file as a string with a `// @sourceURL` declaration which makes the WebKit inspector treat them as separate files.

Comment: @PeterWagenet I figured that out and answered my own question. The problem is that **ember-todos** app on github showcasing using rake-pipeline is extremely out of date. Assetfile doesn't use **string** mode and the copy of **minispade.js** being used is very old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the issue. The minispade filter supports an "string" option. With this option set to true, the minispade filter appends a "sourceUrl" comment at the end of each module. This is later picked up by Firebug or Web-Inspector to show your files individually instead of one single file.

From: [Minispade Filter on Github](https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters/blob/master/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/minispade_filter.rb)

> ```
> #   @option options [Boolean] :string If true, compiles the output as
> #   a String instead of a closure. This means that @sourceURL can be
> #   appended for good stack traces and debugging.
> ```

The catch is that the Assetfile in the [Ember Todos](https://github.com/emberjs/todos) example which showcases using rake-pipeline doesn't have this set to true. Once you modify your copy of the Assetfile, you are good with debugging.

Another open issue with the repo is the extremely old copy of minispade it uses. So if you are checking out that repo, make sure you update your minispade.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a [small hackable rake-pipeline stack](https://github.com/ahx/ember-pipeline) that uses the minispade string feature along with optional coffee-script compilation, handlebars precompiling, compression when running in  production and so on.